# Add dynamically checkboxes for each item i Linear Layout that came from excel

Tags: java, android, xml

I started to import my excel information to show in android. Now I want to add checkboxes for every column passed from excel in order to save the ones i´ve selected and put them in other activity. Can someone help me?

https://postimg.org/image/9ysb2vj8t/  **Here is an image to give an example of whats going on with my app**

**This is my java file**

```
public void Order(View v){
            try{
                String xx="";
                AssetManager am = getAssets();
                InputStream is = am.open("torab.xls");
                Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
                Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
                int row = s.getRows();
                int column = s.getColumns();

                for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){

                    for(int j=0; j<column; j++){
                        Cell z = s.getCell(j,i);
                        xx= xx + z.getContents();

                    }

                  xx = xx +"\n";
                    RelativeLayout linear=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    for(int p=0;p<column;p++){

                        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
                        checkBox.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                        linear.addView(checkBox);

                    }

                }

                Display(xx);

            }
            catch(Exception e){


            }
    }


    public void Display(String value){
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText(value);

    }

    public void comparar(View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Bluetooth.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**This is my xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.altran.vitor.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:text="Gerar Dados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:onClick="Order"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Comparar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="comparar"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">


        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I will me forever grateful if you help me with this problem.**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Display the column text with a checkbox on its side?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want to do. You see, I need the checkbox in order to filter the information that comes from excel, because I will allow the user to choose the items he wants and then store those selected textviews in other activity

Comment: I see. I believe you'll need to create a horizontal `LinearLayout` for each row and append it to your root view, or you could use something like a `ListView` with those two buttons on the bottom of the screen, and add new items to its adapter on the fly.

Comment: The thing is that when I create a list view, he only populates Item1. And by that i can´t separate the items that come from excel

Comment: You have to create a custom adapter for that. I'll write an answer.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/android-listview/checkbox-in-listview--event-handling--1